# get reference to external library xml modules

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I am using the [MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) of navasmdc.

Now I just want to get a reference to the Button and I get the issue:

> Incompatible types:
>   required: com.gc.materialdesign.views.buttonflat
>   found: android.view.view

My code is as follows:

```
   (...)

    ButtonFlat cmdNextButton;

    (...)

      @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration_page_stufe, container, false);

            cmdNextButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.registration_button_next);

            return rootView;
        }

    (...)
```

In my xml is simply the button:

```
 <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
                android:id="@+id/registration_button_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="weiter" />
```

I do not understand why I get that issue because the button I create in code is from the library class I use. Android studio even imported it automatically...

Answer (score 1):

The [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) method returns a View, and you need to cast it to what type of View it is.  You would need to do this for a regular Button as well.

You can see in [this example](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesignLibrary/MaterialDesign/src/main/java/com/gc/materialdesign/widgets/Dialog.java) the correct way to assign a ButtonFlat reference.

Just cast the result of `findViewById()`, and it should work:

```java
cmdNextButton = (ButtonFlat) rootView.findViewById(R.id.registration_button_next);
```